# What is this table trying to convey? Why do sequential reads happen faster than random reads?

Tags: performance, caching, memory

I was shown this table in the context of data processing and big data.

[image: strange table]

What are the bars actually measuring? The mechanism of a device for reading always has the same speed: e.g. it's not as if a hard drive thinks "ok, this data is sequential so I'll increase the amount which the head reads".

I was told it happens because of the cache, though it's sort of misleading to say that the actual read speed is faster if it's the cache that's responsible. Does this happen because an entire page is loaded from secondary storage to primary and if it's sequential than a larger portion of the page would be used then if it was random? This seems like a very academic perspective.

I'm not sure if I should've posted this question above the previous paragraph, but are we talking about 1) how long a device takes to read something, 2) how long it takes for a device to read something and pass it to the next level in the memory hierarchy, 3) or how long a device takes to read something and pass it to the processor? Come to think of it I'm not sure there's a difference between the first two: say you have an SSD that has read speed of x and RAM that has read speed of y. Then for something to be loaded into ram, would it take `(x+y)*size_of_page` time or just `x*size_of_page`? Obviously there's many different caches a long the way: hard drives [have a buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer), I don't know if SSD do, any CPUs can have L1, L2 or any number of caches. It really seems like this table needs more of an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two relevant effects at play.

The first and major effect is that all data transfers from the 3 locations mentioned happen in blocks bigger than a single integer value. From HDD or SSD to main memory, block sizes are typically 4kB or bigger (file system cluster size). From main memory to cache, data transfers are typically 64-256 bytes (cache line size).

The second effect is that because most access is sequential, storage is optimized for this. Hard disk file systems store files consecutively, so the hard disk read head doesn't need to move to get the next cluster. The disk just rotates. Only after one rotation does the head move, by a single step. A random *seek* takes milliseconds, in comparison. But even SSD's have to wait for a new address, whereas for a sequential read the next address can be *predicted*.

Comment: Thanks, what's the difference between a page and block in the context of transferring data from secondary storage to primary?

Comment: @Celeritas: The terms do not have a precise and universal meaning. For instance, some secondary storage is named "block storage" to distinguish it from "file storage", where the difference is that the former organizes the storage in numbered blocks and the latter in named files. A SSD is block storage, a NAS usually is organized as file storage. But those "blocks" of an SSD are more accurately known as sectors. "Pages" however are a way to organize primary storage (RAM),which can however be swapped to secondary storage when RAM is full.

Answer (score 2):

We are talking about how much time elapses between the processor requesting for the data and the processor getting the data it requested. This involves several steps, depending upon the memory architecture and read policy (look through look-aside, etc.)

It takes less time for the processor to get the data it requested for if the data is available in the cache. This is because cache access is very fast compared to main memory access.

When a processor requests for some data value (say an integer), and the data is not present in the cache, it is brought into the cache from the main memory, and then given to the processor from the cache. However, the integer is *not the only data that is brought into the cache.*  A whole *cache line*(may be 128 bytes, for example) is brought into the cache.

Now let's look at the two scenarios:

**Sequential access:**
Main memory access is only required for getting the *first* value, because the values stored in memory locations close to this  (and thus belonging to the same page) are all loaded into the cache during this first memory access. Thus, the subsequent requests for data will happen faster, as the data will be present in the cache and there won't be a cache miss every single time.

**Random access:**
In this case, there will be a cache miss for almost all requests for data (not just the first one) because the data is being accessed from random memory locations, not consecutive memory locations.

This is why it is better to write this code:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
     cout<<array[i][j];
  }
}
```

and not this code:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
  for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
     cout<<array[j][i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Memory is indeed organized in pages, but the granularity of caches is much smaller. A typical x86 implementation has 4kB and 2MB pages, but 128 byte cache lines. (Edited)

Comment: So if we're talking about "how much time elapses between the processor requesting for the data and the processor getting the data it requested" then of course SSD and HD are going to be slower than if the data is already in RAM.